# AS3 blur filter onto a linestyle

Tags: actionscript-3, blur

Is there a way to add a blur filter to a linestyle? Such as

```
var myBlurFilter:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter();

something.graphics.linestyle().filters = {myBlurFilter};
```

obviously this would not work, but is there a way to make it work? Perhaps a different method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters is a property of DisplayObject. Hence you should add the filter to your `something` object. Which means you should separate the line with the blur in different object and add filter to it, leaving other graphic not blurred :)

Cheers!

Comment: Indeed that would work in normal cases, but my `something` object happens to be what I store all my graphics on, so that would blur them anyways. Which is why I need the specific linestyle blurred.

Comment: It works like in Flash IDE - if you apply blur filter to an object, everything inside it will be blurred. Think of `graphics` as the normal drawings inside a MovieClip that you do with some tools. Which means that you cannot blur one specific drawing, if you don't convert it to some kind of actual DisplayObject. Sorry to say it, but if you can't have multiple objects to store graphics inside - there's no other way.

Comment: Well if it helps any - what this is will be a drawing application. And i've seen other apps with blur (just blurring the linestyle drawn and no other graphics on the `something`). I'm guessing the fact i'm trying to use a filter is the problem - but I know of no other methods for blur. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: If so - I will advise you to use different Sprite for each different draw that you make. This way you would be able to do an Undo function, as well as modify different objects - layers, color changes, filters (all kind), etc. Good luck!